# Python cassandra driver - SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: python, ssl, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to connect to a cassandra node that has SSL enabled, using the datastax cassandra driver, like this:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider 

import ssl
ip = <ip>
ap = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=<username>, password=<password>) 

ssl_options = {
  'ca_certs': <path to PEM file>,
  'ssl_version': ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
  }
cluster = Cluster([ip], auth_provider=ap, ssl_options=ssl_options)
session = cluster.connect()
```

I can successfully connect to the node using `pycassa`, but I was trying to switch to using `datastax driver` for this.

The above code throws the following exception:

```
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {<ip>: error(1, u"Tried connecting to [(<ip>, <port>)]. Last error: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:590)")})
```

I know the server accepts PROTOCOL_TLSv1, since it's the default protocol in pycassa.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error commonly occurs when trying to connect with SSL on a socket that is not negotiating SSL.

Confirm that SSL is enabled in the server, and for the port to which you are connecting. I think this should be evident in the server system log.

Comment: I feel so stupid now ... SSL was disabled on the server. Thanks for your reply!